# How to vectorize a bitmap for a specific color range?

Tags: vector, inkscape

I'd like to vectorize only specific colors of a bitmap. I have a bitmap with different colors and blue lines or shapes, and a Map with rivers and lakes.
I'd like to extract these rivers and lakes as vectorized objects.

Is this possible?

What I tried so far:
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> -> Color quantizizing. But I do not get the expected results. It would be good to specify a color range that should be vectorized.

Comment: You need to specify an appropriate number of colors ('Scans') for the 'Multiple Scans' : 'Colors' option, then you will be able to ungroup the result and remove everything but the blue scan.

Make sure to not have 'Stack scans' checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prepare the image for tracing in a **raster editor**, removing the colors you do not want traced.

Trying the isolate and then trace in one app is more trouble than its worth.

At the very least, trace everything and then once it's vector, delete the pieces you don't want.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I accepted the answer. Only one question. I already searched the internet, but was not successfull. What "raster editor" do you prefer ?